# Quick help- Regular Expression to invalidate default form value input

Tags: regex

I have a form with default values. For example, in the name field, it says 'Name' without the quotations. I want the form to be invalidated (based on the regular expression) when the form is submitted with a default value, such as Name.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly was your question?

Comment: @Ingo not sure i follow. regardless, this is resolved. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

For example, if the default value is '**Name**', the regular expression used for validation should be ^(?!Name).*$  -  matches on everything that is not exactly the string 'Name'.

Answer (score 0):

Know your default values and match on them. There is no magic regex escape character that means "default form value, whatever it was".

Comment: i guess i wasn't clear. @lawrence seems to have caught my drift.

Comment: @vul: He said essentially the same and only included a regex so that you're satisfied since you were looking for a regex. He still maintains that regular expressions are not the suitable tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems like overkill for this, just match against the default value.  If you wanted to add a little regex intelligence you could use: `/^[[:blank:]]*name[[:blank:]]*$/i` to match against 'name' whether it is in uppercase or lowercase and whether any spaces have been put around it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex

```
^(?!Name).*$
```

matches any string that does no have the string `Name` in the beginning of it. So it would not match:

```
Name
Namea
Nameb
```

If you want to disallow only the string `Name` you can use the regex:

```
^(?!Name$)(.*)$
```

[**Rubular Link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/xBbxyy07Qh)